# Function in Python to extract web Data

Tags: python, performance, regex, web-scraping

I developed this feature that I think can be improved quite a bit. The result is the desired one, but it took me many lines of code. Any idea to optimize it?

```
import json
import urllib.request

dni = 71179047
    
def get_cuit(dni):
    request = urllib.request.Request('https://www.cuitonline.com/search.php?q=' + str(dni))
    response = urllib.request.urlopen(request)
    data_content = response.read()
    html = data_content.decode('ISO-8859-1')
    cuit = re.findall(r"\(?\b[0-9]{2}\)?-?[0-9]{7,8}-[0-9]{1}\b", html)[0]
    result = re.sub('[^0-9]','', cuit)
    return result

get_cuit(dni)
```

Comment: It's cliché, but: Do not parse HTML with regexes. Do not parse HTML with regexes. [Do not parse HTML with regexes.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

- Use Requests for HTTP and let it deal with the encoding
- Do not bake the query into the URL string
- Use BeautifulSoup for HTML parsing
- Use typehints

Nice and simple:

```
from requests import get
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def get_cuit(dni: int) -> str:
    with get(
        'https://www.cuitonline.com/search.php',
        params={'q': dni},
    ) as resp:
        resp.raise_for_status()
        doc = BeautifulSoup(resp.text, 'html.parser')

    span = doc.find('span', class_='cuit')
    return span.text


print(get_cuit(71_179_047))
```

Comment: As you said, 'nice and simple'. Thanks! ;)

Comment: @Raymont BeautifulSoup really helps too. If you aren't familiar with it, I highly recommend checking it out to see what it can do.

Comment: from-importing `get` would be confusing in larger programs, its better to just use the full name

Comment: @Reinderien Why do you use `context manager` when making a `GET` request?

Comment: @KonstantinKostanzhoglo It ensures that the response stream is closed. This is more important when manipulating a raw stream directly, but it's better to get in the habit of closing it anyway.

Comment: Why do Python devs tend to prefer `from requests import get`/`get(foo)` over `import requests`/`requests.get(foo)`? It just seems very short-sighted to me. Surely, reading `requests.get(foo)` is more informative/self-explanatory than just reading `get(foo)`? In the latter case, I'd have no idea where this `get` came from unless I scrolled all the way up to check all the import statements. Why not just keep namespaces separate? Ease of reading is vastly more important than ease of writing.

Comment: @Will This is a 12-line program. The provenance of `get` is somewhat painfully obvious. In a much longer file, it would be worth considering the other `import` style.

Comment: Reading your answer just happened to remind me that I don't see the merit of the `from X import Y` import style in any case, generally speaking. That said, I admit that it isn't a big deal per se in your specific example code (even if `get` seems overly generic to me), and that this wasn't the ideal place to express that notion.

Answer (score 5):

Couple additional points to what @Reinderien mentioned:

- if you would need to execute this function often, consider initializing a [`requests.Session()`](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/advanced/#session-objects) and re-using it for subsequent requests
- you could improve the speed of HTML parsing here as well:

  - use `lxml` instead of `html.parser` (`lxml` needs to be installed):

    ```
    doc = BeautifulSoup(resp.text, 'lxml')
    ```
  - since you are looking for a single element, [`SoupStrainer`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#parsing-only-part-of-a-document) would really help out to allow your parser not waste time and resources parsing other parts of HTML:

    ```
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, SoupStrainer

    parse_only = SoupStrainer('span', class_='cuit')
    doc = BeautifulSoup(resp.text, 'lxml', parse_only=parse_only)
    ```

Answer (score 4):

If you *did* have to use a regular expression for this task (which you shouldn't in this case - see the other answer), you could improve it by:

- `[0-9]` is equivalent to `\d`, a digit character
- A number inside brackets indicates the number of times the previous token should be repeated. In the case of `{1}`, it's superfluous - you can leave out the brackets entirely and the token will be matched exactly once anyway.

```
\(?\b\d{2}\)?-?\d{7,8}-\d\b
```

- Since you don't want *all* matches, but just the *first* match, `.search` could be a bit more appropriate than using `.findall` to find all matches followed by extracting the `[0]`th match.